# The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

Tags: ios, xcode5

I want to add repository in my XCode5.0. When I am trying to connect svn repository then it is not connecting and giving error like "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)". So can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: Yes it is based on IP.

Comment: can u provide a structure of your url

Comment: yes it is like:[link](https://192.168.1.31/svn/projectname)

Comment: @manujmv I have given the url structure.Will you please tell me the solution??

Comment: @Ashok: try ping this ip and tell me what u got?

Comment: Sorry @manujmv for delay because of network problem I didn't get ur message.I tried with your suggestion and I got the following:    ping 192.168.1.31
PING 192.168.1.31 (192.168.1.31): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.31: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=82.384 ms

Comment: Have you fix this issue ? @manujmv i got same problem , i have ping to server and it gives responce `64 bytes from 192.168.1.215: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=0.999 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.215: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.980 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.215: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.900 ms` , can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use address like http://base.server.com/. It is a bug in XCode and not resolved in XCode 5.1 DP also. That was a answer once I found.

Comment: Thanks @Rashad let me try it

Comment: No its not working.Actually I am using https instead of http.

Comment: do you have any other solution regarding this problem please provide me.